# how can i handle dynamically changing ids on my webpage using selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, dynamic

Here is my code

```
<mat-error class="mat-error" role="alert" id="mat-error-0">  </mat-error>
<mat-error class="mat-error" role="alert" id="mat-error-1">  </mat-error>
```

Here mat-error-0 will change to mat-error-1 on page refresh and mat-error-1 will change to mat-error-2 and so on..

There is no unique class or role attribute here that i can take here.

Please advise.

Comment: *Here is my code*... No. It's just an HTML sample. Where is **your** code?

Comment: I have updated with my code . Please change the marking to +ve so other can also help

Comment: I see no updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following xpath

```
//mat-error[text()='Please enter a valid To date']
//mat-error[text()='Please enter a valid From date']
```

Comment: Thanks but the error message will change based upon the user inputs. I want to give the unique ids to validate both the error messages for both these fields.

Comment: I did little modification in my code and it worked for me ..                 
//mat-error[contains(text(),'"+please enter a valid To/From Date+"')]

Comment: Sorry for being inactive. There are cases where the developer might accidentally add additional spaces. In that case, as u mentioned  'contains text()' will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As long as innerHTML stays consistent after refreshing the page, you can use Xpath to find the element. e.g. the following Xpath can locate *To date* webElement.

```
//mat-error[contains(.,'valid To date')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Xpath for dynamically changing id.

```
//mat-error[starts-with(@id,'mat-error')]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i want to give the unique ids for both the error messages. This will work if i need to match the error message for one of the field  (to or From)

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared, as the `id` keeps changing so you have to construct dynamic *xpath* to identify both the elements as follows :

- Element with text as **Please enter a valid To date** :

  ```
  //mat-error[@class='mat-error' and starts-with(@id,'mat-error') and contains(.,'To')]
  ```
- Element with text as **Please enter a valid From date** :

  ```
  //mat-error[@class='mat-error' and starts-with(@id,'mat-error') and contains(.,'From')]
  ```

Comment: sorry but the error messages will keep on changing as per user inputs. This'll not work. Any other solution please?

Comment: @Lucky As per the scope of this question with only 2 nodes I am sure my solution will work for you. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement. StackOveflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: thanks but my question was regarding the ids for both the fields. In your case you are also checking To and From also which is just a message inside these tags and that keep on changing as well. In this question, i clearly mentioned about the ids which will keep on changing. Please let me know if i need to rephrase it again

Comment: @Lucky You have changed the question after receiving effective answers from the StackOverflow volunteers which is completely **unethical** as per _StackOverflow standards_. Please revert back your question and accept the answer if either of them have catered to your question and raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: Never mind Debanjan, i just cleared the message to remove any ambiguity. Question is still the same